# Chrome extension MV3: contentPort.onMessage taking priority over nativePort.onMessage service worker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm migrating a MV2 extension to MV3 and as part of that process obviously switching to a background service worker.

My content script connects to the background service worker with the following API and then sets up some listeners on the port.

```
this.port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: CONTENT_BG_PROXY_CONNECTION_NAME});
```

In the service worker I register to listen for this connection and in response to that listen to messages on that port. I also then create my Native Messaging Host connection and listen for messages on that port as well (besides some additional busioness logci that I don't think matters

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {

    if(port.name == CONTENT_BG_PROXY_CONNECTION_NAME) {
        let contentPort = port;

        let nativePort = chrome.runtime.connectNative(NATIVE_MESSAGING_APP_NAME);
        nativePort.onMessage.addListener(function(message) { 
            //...
            contentPort.postMessage(message);
        });

        contentPort.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
            
            //...
            nativePort.postMessage(message);
            
        });
    }
});
```

The issue is if the content script is sending a lot of messages - worst case maybe 60 a second - then the contentPort.onMessage callback is continually triggered however the responses from the native host are not being processed as nativePort.onMessage is not being triggered.

Once I stop the content script sending messages all of a sudden all of those pending responses start being processed in nativePort.onMessage.

I'm sure there's some rate limiting I can do or something, but this scenario worked perfectly with MV2. Processing seemed to be split between event handlers.

Is there a way to give equal priority to these event handlers, or in fact give higher priority to the messages coming back from the native host?

Comment: Every connection from **content -> background** creates a new connection from **background -> native** - Do you inject the content script into a single tab only, or into multiple tabs that are open at the same time?

Comment: Yes, this is essentially creating a 1:1 mapping between native and content. We inject into multiple tabs that are open at the same time but it's unlikely anything, but the active tab is actually sending messages. That is unchanged in design from MV2 and reproduces this issue with a single open tab.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem.

- Manjaro Linux
- Chromium 112.0.5615.49 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-Bit)
- an old computer (what some people would call a "potato")

`manifest.json`

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "port_background_native_simple",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "js": ["content_script.js"]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
        "action": {
    },
    "permissions": [
        "nativeMessaging"
    ]
}
```

`background.js`

```
let message_counter = 1;

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    if(port.name == "port_background_native_simple") {
        let contentPort = port;
        let nativePort = chrome.runtime.connectNative("port_background_native_simple");
        nativePort.onMessage.addListener(function(message) { 
            console.log("nativePort.onMessage", message + " / " + message_counter);
            contentPort.postMessage(message);
            message_counter++;
        });
        contentPort.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
            console.log("contentPort.onMessage", message + " / " + message_counter);
            nativePort.postMessage(message);
        });
    }
});
```

`content_script.js`

```
this.port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "port_background_native_simple"});
setInterval(() => {
    this.port.postMessage("test message");
}, Math.round(1000 / 60));
```

`port_background_native_simple.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u

# Note that running python with the `-u` flag is required on Windows,
# in order to ensure that stdin and stdout are opened in binary, rather
# than text, mode.

import os
import json
import sys
import struct
import psutil

# Read a message from stdin and decode it.
def get_message():
    raw_length = sys.stdin.buffer.read(4)
    if not raw_length:
        sys.exit(0)
    message_length = struct.unpack("=I", raw_length)[0]
    message = sys.stdin.buffer.read(message_length).decode("utf-8")
    return json.loads(message)

# Encode a message for transmission, given its content.
def encode_message(message_content):
    encoded_content = json.dumps(message_content).encode("utf-8")
    encoded_length = struct.pack("=I", len(encoded_content))
    # use struct.pack("10s", bytes), to pack a string of the length of 10 characters
    return {"length": encoded_length, "content": struct.pack(str(len(encoded_content))+"s",encoded_content)}

# Send an encoded message to stdout.
def send_message(encoded_message):
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(encoded_message["length"])
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(encoded_message["content"])
    sys.stdout.buffer.flush()

try:
    while True:
        message = get_message()
        sys.stderr.write(message + "\n")
        send_message(encode_message(message))
except Exception as e:
    send_message(encode_message(str(e)))
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this! I'm using Windows and an .exe but let me try simplifying my repro further, more in line with yours and try out your repro too. If I can still Repro perhaps, I can figure out something more specific.